# Image upload form in PHP does nothing, no error

Tags: php, file-upload

I have the following PHP code that I am using to upload an image to MySQL. When I click submit nothing happens.

```
include ("connect.php");
session_start();
$login = $_SESSION['wname'];

if((@$_POST['submit'])&&(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))){
  // properties of the uploaded file
  $name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
  $type = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
  $size = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
  $temp = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
  $error = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

  if($name){
    die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
  } else {
    $place = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$place);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE page SET pid_image_name = '$place' WHERE wname = '$login' ");
    die("upload complete <a href='index.php'>View image</a>");
    echo "Upload complete!";
  }
} else {
  die("select a file"); 
}
```

Here's my form:

```
<form action='up.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form'> 
<input type='file' name='myfile'>
<p> <input type='submit' name='submit' value="upload">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Nothing happens" indicates that you aren't displaying error messages or haven't even tried to debug ... get some (error)output first.

Comment: @ChrisR - yup, that's what I'm thinking...

Comment: no i did that and i fix what error i had, but this time i get nada.

Comment: We are talking about logic errors, not syntax errors. No language will catch a logic error.

Comment: i check the code again and it like its not executing this part of the code   if($name){
    die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
  } else {
    $place = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$place);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE page SET pid_image_name = '$place' WHERE wname = '$login' ");
    die("upload complete <a href='index.php'>View image</a>");
    echo "Upload complete!";
  }
} it only echo out select a file

Answer (score 3):

Another important parameter to check out in php.ini is post_max_size. If you set upload_max_filesize > post_max_size the result is that no data is written to $_POST nor $_FILES for files which sizes exceed post_max_size but are below upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 2):

1. Format you're code.
2. Are you submitting the actual HTML form (not the PHP code) as html/multipart?? I am willing to be you're not. (`enctype="multipart/form-data" needs added to your form tag!`)
3. Learn to debug - actually put conditions elsewhere and see where your code is failing!

Comment: Agree. Let's see your HTML, I'm thinking the form is not multipart either.

Comment: <html>
upload file...<br>
<form action='up.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form'>
<input type='file' name='myfile'><p> 
<input type='submit' name='submit' value="upload">


</html>

Comment: @user621799 - FORMAT YOUR CODE!

Comment: @user621799 - That's also not Valid HTML. You never close your form and you don't even have a submit button! Post your full HTML form, FORMATTED

Comment: @user621799: Is this a joke? :-)

Comment: nada, i check the code again and it like its not executing this part of the code   if($name){
    die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
  } else {
    $place = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$place);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE page SET pid_image_name = '$place' WHERE wname = '$login' ");
    die("upload complete <a href='index.php'>View image</a>");
    echo "Upload complete!";
  }
} it only echo out select a file

Comment: okay. honestly. im a pretty patient person. im not trying to help you resolve this issue anymore. I've asked you countless times to format your code and you have not. furthermore, you have indicated that you have not even tried to debug your code on your own.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML for have you got `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?
Something like this:

```
<form action='submit.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Edit 1**:
if you do this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $place)){
   echo "did move file<br />";
}else{
   echo "move failed<br />";
}
```

You will get **move failed** (Or I do with your code)

**Edit 2**
I found your problem:
 you misspelt the temp-dir variable: you defined `$temp` but in the `move_uploaded_file` you asked for `$tmp_name` so here the correct code:
 `move_uploaded_file($temp, $place);`

Comment: here is the form, i do have that line of code already  <html>
upload file...<br>
<form action='up.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form'>
<input type='file' name='myfile'><p> 
<input type='submit' name='submit' value="upload">


</html>

Comment: nada, i check the code again and it like its not executing this part of the code   if($name){
    die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
  } else {
    $place = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$place);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE page SET pid_image_name = '$place' WHERE wname = '$login' ");
    die("upload complete <a href='index.php'>View image</a>");
    echo "Upload complete!";
  }
} it only echo out select a file

Comment: Why are you checking for the `$name` if you are checking for an error? Shouldn't you use `$error`?

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you can't see any errors activate error reporting by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` right after the php tag.

Comment: nada, i check the code again and it like its not executing this part of the code   if($name){
    die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
  } else {
    $place = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$place);
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE page SET pid_image_name = '$place' WHERE wname = '$login' ");
    die("upload complete <a href='index.php'>View image</a>");
    echo "Upload complete!";
  }
} it only echo select a file